# Wordpress site would not work after changing siteurl and home

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Noticed that by default wordpress keeps the site name www.mysite.com/wordpress but we wanted to change it to www.mysite.com/blog. Based on the documentation and other stackoverflow posts, it's as simple as making following changes.

1. override WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME in wp-config.php
2. Fix .htaccess entries to have correct rewrite rules
3. Update Permalinks settings

Or manually update wp_options table if you are unable to get into WP admin console.

Also followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101412/404-error-and-redirect-after-moving-wordpress-site-from-live-to-localhost) but still no luck, getting 404 errors when going to the new URL.

Comment: If you change serialized content in the database, and the strings aren't exactly the same length, PHP will white screen of death you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason none of the approaches including what Hugo mentioned above didn't work for me. I then renamed the root WP installation directory from 'wordpress' to 'blog' to math the URL and everything is working now.

I am not sure why I had to do this but it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress keep URL information in database.
You need to update them as well.
Perform search and replace into your DB to replace your existing URL with the new one :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'Existing URL', 'New URL') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'Existing URL', 'New URL');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'Existing URL','New URL');

UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'Existing URL','New URL');

UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, 'Existing URL','New URL');

UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = replace(comment_content , 'Existing URL','New URL');
```

*NB : wp_ change it to your wordpress installation prefix*

You can also use this to go faster : https://rudrastyh.com/tools/sql-queries-generator. There is also some WP Plugins to perform search and replace within your WP DB.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I tried this but it didn't work.